# Merging two CNNs with an additional input vector to a resulting third CNN in keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, convolution

The architecture is two identical networks receiving different inputs. The first network receives a real-valued vector, the second receives a Boolean-valued vector. 
The first layer of each network is a convolutional layer with 16 filters of size 4x4. The second layer of each network is a convolutional layer with 32 filters of size 2x2.

The outputs of these two networks and a vector P(7x4), are combined and input to two fully-connected layers of 128 and then 64 neurons. The output layer is |A| (i.e., four) neurons.

How would I go about building this architecture in keras? Particularly with respect to the P vector.

Comment: What is a size of your input? Do you expect this two networks to have the same weights or can they have different weights?

Comment: Input size is a boolean/real-valued matrix of size 16x12 and weights may be different

Comment: Did you find an answer?